# why child theme style sheet in wordpress editor is blank?

Tags: child-theme

I have created a child theme using ftp and the site is running well. But problem is when I am opening appearance > editor from dashboard the child theme style sheet is displaying blank page where from ftp server the style sheet looks everything okay with all it's codes and characters.

Comment: Have you checked file permissions for the style sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the styles.css in the child theme folder has the proper  tags (opening and closing).

Child themes, when first created, usually have a blank styles.css file, with just the open/close 'styles' tag.

Although probably not the answer, perhaps extra spacing is before the opening  tag? (Shouldn't make a difference if there is...)